# Is there a stringgrid in objective-c cocoa framework as there is in Delphi

Tags: objective-c, delphi, tstringgrid

Is there a StringGrid in the Cocoa Framework or has anybody implemented one that would be like the one in Delphi?

Comment: The number of people who've used Delphi and Cocoa is very small. How about describing this "StringGrid" so we have some idea of what it's supposed to do?

Comment: Here are a few links thanks to Leonardo M. Rame' that explains a stringrid in Delphi.

http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/TStringGrid_Class
http://hiderin.air-nifty.com/photos/uncategorized/2008/01/04/stringgrid_2.png
http://www.asiplease.net/computing/delphi/string_grid_component.htm

Basically, it is a simple grid component (like a table or Matrix) that allows one to save string data in its cells. There is no need for a datasource and you can set and access the data with commands like stringgrid1.cells[x,y]. There is a count, noofcolumns, noofrows properties that you can set or access.

Comment: Since Free Pascal access COCOA, it is rising :-)

Answer (score 1):

From what google gave me I believe you mean simple `NSTableView`?

Comment: No. Not an NSTableView. The stringgrid component in Delphi is not nearly as complicated as an NSTableView. 
You drag the component on a form and it is a grid like a table or matrix and you can populate its cells with string data. It has count,noofrows,noofcolumns,etc properties that you could set or get. No need for a datasource and for protocols and their complications.

Comment: uh... so NSTableView is basically StringGrid on steroids?

Comment: Then it's just NSMatrix populated with NSTextFields. Not sure about the access and persistence though...

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of links showing the TStringGrid control:

```
http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/TStringGrid_Class
http://hiderin.air-nifty.com/photos/uncategorized/2008/01/04/stringgrid_2.png
http://www.asiplease.net/computing/delphi/string_grid_component.htm
```

*P.S.: This answer should appear as a comment for NSResponder question, but, since I can't find the "Add Comments" link, I added this comment as an Answer.*

Comment: You can comment others' posts once you get 50 reputation points.